# Got NoClassDefFoundError: wrong name with Windows path

Tags: java, classloader, urlclassloader

I have a TEST123.class in the path below.

D:/Users/XXX/Desktop/sem-material-job/sem-material-job/sem-material-freemarkerjob/target/classes/com/ctrip/market/sem/freemarkerjob/dynamicjava/

Then I run the try clause below to load the class by URLClassLoader , however it give me the exception ava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: TEST123 (wrong name:, how to solve the exception?

```
ava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: TEST123 (wrong name: com/ctrip/market/sem/freemarkerjob/dynamicjava/TEST123)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)

   try {
                URLClassLoader mycl = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { new URL(
                        "file:///D:/Users/XXX/Desktop/sem-material-job/sem-material-job/sem-material-freemarkerjob/target/classes/com/ctrip/market/sem/freemarkerjob/dynamicjava/") });
                Class c2 = mycl.loadClass("TEST123");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Seems like there is a coflict of java classes. There are two or more implementation of class URLClassLoader. Please check there may be two implementation in different jars.

Comment: The URLClassLoader is from the package java.net.URLClassLoader; so there should be one implementation. from the error message "NoClassDefFoundError: TEST123 (wrong name:" , it seems the path I specified is wrong , however I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: addurl upto target/classes and use full qualified class name to load the class

Comment: The exception throw when run at the line   Class c2 = mycl.loadClass("TEST123");

Comment: I think you have to change your URL to point to classpath and load class by package name, like this `URLClassLoader mycl = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { new URL(
                        "file:///D:/Users/XXX/Desktop/sem-material-job/sem-material-job/sem-material-freemarkerjob/target/classes/") });
                Class c2 = mycl.loadClass("com.ctrip.market.sem.freemarkerjob.dynamicjava.TEST123");`

If it works, thank you to tell me to change this comment in answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to change your URL to point to classpath and load class by package name, like this

```
URLClassLoader mycl = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { 
new URL("file:///D:/Users/XXX/Desktop/sem-material-job/sem-material-‌​job/sem-material-fre‌​emarkerjob/target/cl‌​asses/") }); 

Class c2 = mycl.loadClass("com.ctrip.market.sem.freemarkerjob.dynamicja‌​va.TEST123");
```

Comment: If we can change the absolutely path file:///D:/Users/XXX/Desktop/sem-material-job/sem-material-job/sem-material-freemarkerjob/target/classes/  to related path ,as we have to run the program to Linux, so the Windows path D:/Users/XXX/.. is invalid.

Comment: it depends on your needs, there are different ways to set a path related to plateforme.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to load class `TEST123` but your `TEST123.class` file contains class `com.ctrip.market.sem.freemarkerjob.dynamicjava.TEST123`. What's the package in the first line of `TEST123.java`? Changing your code to

```
URLClassLoader mycl = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { 
        new URL("file:///D:/Users/XXX/Desktop/sem-material-job/sem-material-job/sem-material-freemarkerjob/target/classes/") });
Class c2 = mycl.loadClass("com.ctrip.market.sem.freemarkerjob.dynamicjava.TEST123");
```

Should work.

Comment: Yes,  you and  andolsi  gave the correct answer, thank you so much.